# Integral function (x,y) in python

Tags: python, module, integral

I have a function like:

```
(np.sqrt((X)**2 + (Y)**2))/(np.sqrt((X)**2 + (Y)**2 + d**2))
```

I wrote a program for calculating integral by using series:

```
for i in range (num): # for X
print i
Y=(-distance)
for j in range(num): # for Y
    f=(np.sqrt((X)**2 + (Y)**2))/(np.sqrt((X)**2 + (Y)**2 + d**2))
    Y=Y+delta
    sum+=(f*(delta**2))/((2*distance)**2)
X=X+delta
print sum
```

And It works fine for me.. But it takes too long for some complex function.

Is there any python module for integrating this function when `-2.0 < X` and `Y < 2.0`? (or something else)

Comment: If you don't have SciPy, you'll probably want to get it: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you want to integrate `fun` between `x` equals `a` and `b` and `y` equals `c` and `d`. In this case what you have to do is:

```
import numpy as np

# Define 'd' to whatever value you need
d = 1. 

# Function to integrate
fun = lambda x, y: np.sqrt(x**2. + y**2.) / np.sqrt(x**2. + y**2. + d**2.)

# Limits of integration
a, b = -2., 2.
c, d = -2., 2.

gfun = lambda x: c
hfun = lambda x: d

# Perform integration
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
int, err = dblquad(fun, a, b, gfun, hfun)
```

If you need more complex limits of integration you just need to change `gfun` and `hfun`. If you are interested in more advanced feature you can take a look at the documentation of `dblquad`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html#scipy.integrate.dblquad

Answer (score 0):

There's a library for this, `scipy.integrate`.
This should be pretty straightforward to do:

```
func = lambda y: (np.sqrt((X)**2 + (Y)**2))/(np.sqrt((X)**2 + (Y)**2 + d**2)) and a == -2 and b == 2
from scipy import integrate
integrate.quad(func, a b)
```

This should do it.  I would consult the documentation for SciPy for more info.

**Edit:** If there are issues, make sure you're using floats instead of ints.